# Https Error in Postman when Send push notification via Rest

Tags: rest, parse-platform, restful-authentication, postman

I'm fairly new To **Parse** with **Rest Api**

I wanna test samples in Their Webistes's ( [Here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide) ) in **Postman** But every time I Post it gives me following Authentication error :

[image]

I Wanna test following code in Postman ( see origin [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications) )

```
    curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 0VoIZO8cgmnyfiuklLLkKkxOX7r" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: UjU5eb5zjic75mPZVdHExYqnneT" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "deviceType": "ios",
        "deviceToken": "0123456789abcdef0123456789cdef0123456789abcdef",
        "channels": [
          ""
        ]
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/installations
```

How Can I resolve this issue ? What is that ? And What is required ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reqeuesting `GET` request and api doc says its `POST` request.

**1) Enter correct url and select POST request method. Add required headers as per the doc.**

[image]

**2) Enter raw JSON data in your request body.**

[image]

**3) You will receive your output. Since api key and application id is not valid so that I received unauthorized error.**

[image]